# object appearing black in edit mode

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, wireframe

i have tried removing doubles and recalculating normal. Also when i go in edit mode with other object there is no such problem.
it is difficult to see mesh is such darkness. please suggest how to overcome this problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It just looks like your mesh has a really dense topology with many vertex, other than reducing the amount of geometry I don't see a way. It is hard to tell from the images alone though, could you post better quality ones, closer to the object

Comment: I does look like so.  But I can also somehow see the lowpoly vertices around the circular parts.  It'd be interesting to see what's really going on in that blend file.

Comment: This looks completely normal to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than what said in above comments, you can customize the color used for unselected vertices (black by default), to whatever you wish:

[image]